# Is there a unix command to count the number of different file types in a directory?

Tags: file, unix, cygwin

I used the `ls | wc -1` command to count the number of files in a directory. Is there a command to count the number of different file types ? Say the directory has 2 text files and one jpeg, the output should be 2 (text and jpeg are the different file types).

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no single command (although you can certainly create one!) to do what you want, but it is quite simple to get your result.  Decide exactly how you want to distinguish file type (filename extension, file content, name, etc.), then use common tools to count the result.  If you are happy with the results printed by the `file` command, perhaps something as simple as:

```
file * | awk '{$1=""}1' | sort -u | wc -l
```

The awk filters out the first column of output (the filename) and the remaining processes in the pipeline count the results.  This is fragile and will break if any of your filenames contain whitespace, so you might want to use `:` for the field separater in `awk` (in which case the solution is fragile and will fail if any filename contains a colon.)

Answer (score -1):

Use `file` to find out the file types. Pipe that through `grep` to filter out things like images etc. and then do a `wc -l`.

Comment: Why the -1? Anyone have suggestions for improvement?